# Html layout for emails

Tags: html, css

I am creating the following layout that is to be used in emails and must be table-based, margins can not be used in it:

http://i60.tinypic.com/14ch2js.jpg

I tried a table-based approach, but can't get it to work. How can I produce such a layout? Thank you for your help.

Comment: We need to see some code of what you already have.

Comment: You have to at least try and then post your code here. SO is here to help you solve your issue, not a resource for others to simply do the work. HINT: Don't use tables, this can be done with `<div>`'s and CSS.

Comment: Why can margins not be used?

Comment: This html layout is for emails, some email-software products do not support margins.

Comment: Oh. I just read that this is meant to be for emails. That REALLY is an important piece of information and should be mentioned in the question.

Comment: I have updated the post with the code done so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on whether area 4 really needs to be an enclosed area, i think this would be easiest:

https://jsfiddle.net/svArtist/Lk3tL4ww/

```css
#container, html, body {
    width:400px;
    height:600px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
}
#i2 {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#31c8ff;
}
#i3 {
    border-radius: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color: #e3ffff;
}
#i1 {
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #bfffff;
}
#container {
    background-color: #2b939e;
}
#foreground {
    position:absolute;
    top: 120px;
    width:100%;
}
#i5 {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 90%;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #fff;
}
#i1, #i2, #i4 {
    text-align:left;
}
#i3 {
    text-align:center;
}
#i6 {
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #207780;
}
#i7 {
    height: 120px;
    background-color: #165451;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="i1">
        <div id="i2">2
            <div id="i3">3</div>
        </div>1</div>
    <div id="foreground">
        <!-- div id="i4">4</div -->
        <div id="i5">5</div>
        <div id="i6">6</div>
        <div id="i7">7</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, Ben, this is exactly what I was trying to achieve with tables. Now I see the div-approach is much better, thank you for your example. Can these margins be omitted somehow?

Comment: well, we're not using margins with any absolute / positive values, but we do need them to center 3 and 5. You might handle this by just setting
left: 5%;
for #i5 and width to 90%, and apply the same technique to #i3

Comment: I tried with #i3 and it works! Yet, left: 5%; for #i5 does not work, I tried to change the position attribute, but it didn't work as well. Here are the updates: https://jsfiddle.net/s2pjyaej/3/. Is there a posibility to move i5 to the right for 5% of the width keeping width: 90%;?

Comment: are paddings OK for you?
[https://jsfiddle.net/svArtist/gcwtmvpp/](https://jsfiddle.net/svArtist/gcwtmvpp/)

Comment: Yes, paddings are OK. Thank you for your help, Ben, it is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/y8yebukc/

```
#container {
    position: relative;
}
#area1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
    background: lightblue;
}
#area2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
    background: red;
}
#area3 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: black;
    top: 150px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, Snorlax, for your response! The layout looks very good. I tried to do this with tables, however without success mainly for the header area 2 that is under area 3 (logo), yet upon area 1. Is it possible to omit margins in your example?

Comment: Why are you using tables with this though? Are you changing each table row's width and height? Use DIVs as suggested above by Joe.

Comment: Just tried with tables, thought with a table it would be easier to create this layout. However, a div-approach might be better, still can't use margins for that.

Comment: Show us the code for the table you got, since you're saying it's easier to do than this.